# Database Testing Webservices Protocol in Loadrunner

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, loadrunner

I used lr_db_connect in web services protocol using load runner version 11 . in that i have used ODBC connection Type ( MYY DB is Oracle ). While running the script i am getting

Data source name not found and no default driver registered

Please let me know why i got this error and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your application is using ODBC as the connection type?

Try recording SQL+ for Windows with the ORACLE protocol

Comment: I tried to record using oracle 2 tier and used oracle Sql developer to connect to the DB , nothing gets recorded . Post recording i am getting "Failed to load oracle2tier2.ibf"

Comment: I did not say to use SQL Developer, which is a Java application using JDBC (not ODBC).   Use SQL Plus for Windows, which is a native ORACLE application which uses OCLIB to connect.   Or, you may find an ODBC architected client to connect with and record ODBC.  JDBC!=ODBC from an API recording perspective (not to mention that one of them runs inside of guest operating system., Java)   Leveraging your core foundation skills in Application Architecture and Development will be critical in identifying and leveraging the correct interfaces for load